# Software-center disappeared from Launcher and won't work after re-install

Tags: software-center

On Gnome desktop. After it disappeared, I attempted to reinstall with:
`sudo apt-get install software-center`. This seemed to work and the file was located in `/usr/bin` but when I issued: `software-center --debug` from the terminal I got this:

```
014-04-19 17:49:33,619 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py', 406, '_introspect_error_handler')'
2014-04-19 17:49:33,619 - dbus.proxies - ERROR - Introspect error on :1.234:/com/ubuntu/Softwarecenter: dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
2014-04-19 17:49:33,621 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py', 409, '_introspect_error_handler')'
2014-04-19 17:49:33,621 - dbus.proxies - DEBUG - Executing introspect queue due to error
2014-04-19 17:50:02,114 - softwarecenter.performance - DEBUG - open the apt cache (in event loop): 3.27234315872
2014-04-19 17:50:03,297 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - DEBUG - refresh with days_delta: 1
2014-04-19 17:50:03,303 - softwarecenter.backend.spawn_helper - DEBUG - running: '['/usr/share/software-center/piston_get_review_stats_helper.py', '--days-delta', '1']' as pid: '15456'
2014-04-19 17:50:03,304 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - DEBUG - _retrieve_votes_from_server started
2014-04-19 17:50:03,328 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2014-04-19 17:50:03,330 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - DEBUG - query for the update-database exception 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name com.ubuntu.Softwarecenter was not provided by any .service files' (probably ok)
2014-04-19 17:50:03,332 - softwarecenter.plugin - DEBUG - no dir ''
2014-04-19 17:50:03,333 - softwarecenter.plugin - DEBUG - no dir '/usr/share/software-center/plugins'
2014-04-19 17:50:03,333 - softwarecenter.plugin - DEBUG - no dir '/home/dad/.local/share/software-center/plugins'
2014-04-19 17:50:03,333 - softwarecenter.plugin - DEBUG - plugins are '[]'
2014-04-19 17:50:03,406 - softwarecenter.performance - DEBUG - create SoftwareCenterApp: 54.832146883
2014-04-19 17:50:03,634 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.utils - INFO - Softwarecenter style provider for ambiance Gtk theme: /usr/share/software-center/ui/gtk3/css/softwarecenter.css
2014-04-19 17:50:05,316 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.panes.viewswitcher - DEBUG - on_transactions_changed '{}'
2014-04-19 17:50:05,323 - softwarecenter.backend.spawn_helper - DEBUG - helper_finished: '15456' '0'
2014-04-19 17:50:05,338 - softwarecenter.backend.spawn_helper - DEBUG - got data for cmd: '['/usr/share/software-center/piston_get_review_stats_helper.py', '--days-delta', '1']'='[<softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0x9d0358c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0x9d0356c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0x9d03b8c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0x9d03aec>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0x9d03b0c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0x9d03a6c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0x9d03a8c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040c0c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040c2c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040bcc>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040bec>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040c6c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040d0c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040cac>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040ccc>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040d2c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040d6c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa0409cc>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040b2c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04078c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04070c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04068c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa0406cc>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04062c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04066c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa0407ac>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04012c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04018c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04016c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04024c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04022c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa0400cc>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04006c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa0401ec>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa0401cc>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04034c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04038c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa0403cc>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa0402cc>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa0402ec>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04028c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04032c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa0403ec>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04044c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040f4c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040f6c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040fec>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040dac>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040d8c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040e2c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040dcc>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040e6c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040e4c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040ecc>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040eac>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa040f2c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04054c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04052c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04058c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04056c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04048c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04046c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa0404ec>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa0404cc>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04060c>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa0405ec>, <softwarecenter.backend.piston.rnrclient_pristine.ReviewsStats object at 0xa04002c>]'
2014-04-19 17:50:05,417 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - DEBUG - on_review_stats_loaded: '5209'
2014-04-19 17:50:12,723 - softwarecenter.db.update - WARNING - error processing: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S' 
2014-04-19 17:50:13,468 - softwarecenter.db.update - WARNING - error processing: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S' 
2014-04-19 17:50:13,676 - softwarecenter.db.update - WARNING - error processing: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S' 
2014-04-19 17:50:14,206 - softwarecenter.db.update - WARNING - error processing: time data '' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d  %H:%M:%S'
```

whereupon the process "hangs"
I have done: `sudo apt-get remove software-center` followed by a reinstall with no joy.
The files keep showing up in `/usr/bin` and `usr/share` but the command doesn't work and nothing gets added to the Launcher, even after I tried:  `software-center -enable-lp`

This is all done on a HP Compaq Desktop with AMD 32bit CPU.

Comment: Just tried your suggestion and the install of synaptic went fine and reinstall of software center seemed to go OK but when I entered: Software-center at the prompt I got this:      -desktop:~$ software-center
2014-04-19 20:35:02,937 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.em - INFO - EM's: 17 15 21
2014-04-19 20:35:06,676 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2014-04-19 20:35:06,911 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.utils - INFO - Softwarecenter style provider for ambiance Gtk theme: /usr/share/software-center/ui/gtk3/css/softwarecenter.c ...etc,

Comment: There were further errors about a date format not being right then the terminal just hung...what to do now?

Answer (score 0):

you can install synaptic package manager(alternative for software center) and then u can try installing software center from synaptic

to install synaptic from terminal

sudo apt-get install synaptic

after installing synaptic search in synaptic for software-center if already installed uninstall and run

sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean

after that restart and try reinstalling that may solve your problem